# Unable to authorize using existing access token with Google API node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-analytics-api

A bit of background first; I've got a PHP-based app which handles the Google OAuth flow and stores the resulting access token in a database. I am able to use this access token perfectly fine in another PHP script, so I don't think the token has expired.

The problem comes when I try to use the access token in a node.js script. I always get this error back from the Google API.

> { [Error: Invalid Credentials]
>     code: undefined,
>     errors:
>      [ { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'authError',
>          message: 'Invalid Credentials',
>          locationType: 'header',
>          location: 'Authorization' } ] }

The node.js code I'm using, for reference, is as follows;

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'CLIENT_SECRET';
var REDIRECT_URL = 'REDIRECT_URL';

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URL);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
});

var analytics = google.analytics('v3');

analytics.management.accounts.list({
    auth : oauth2Client
}, function(err, resp) {
   console.log(err);
   console.log(resp);
});
```

I've tried hard-coding the access_token value in a test script but still, the same result.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: When I have problem accessing API in Node.js, I try using some wrapper libraries just to be sure that something works. I give you two scripts that might help you out https://github.com/sfarthin/ga-analytics https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-googleanalytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through the code for the PHP and Node.js API libs, I've found my answer.

The PHP API Client automatically checks if the token is invalid and then renews it without telling you (from what I can see). My stored token was invalid and I therefore just need to refresh it manually in the Node.js script.